# Redireccionamiento con o sin barra (/) slash al final en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Uso el framework de codeigniter para desarrollo, el problema es que tengo la siguiente url `http://localhost:8080/proyecto/index.php/home/`, con esta url todo funciona de 'maravilla' todo se carga de manera correcta, pero si uso esta url `http://localhost:8080/proyecto/index.php/home` si quito el contra slash del home `/` se carga la pagina pero los datos se pierden, entonces la idea es que cuando se quite ese slash que lo siga redirigiendo `http://localhost:8080/proyecto/index.php/home/`..

esta es la funcion:

```
public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('login'))
        {
            $this->load->view('home');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect(site_url());
        }
    }
```

Agradeceria su colaboracion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar lo que pides de crear un archivo `.htaccess` en la raiz del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Esto para conseguir URL amigables. Te recomiendo que que actives el `mod_rewrite` de tu archivo `httpd.conf` descomentando la siguiente linea:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

De esta forma te evitas el `index.php` de tu URL quedando URL´s de la siguiente manera:

```
http://localhost:8080/proyecto/home
```

Comment: Voy a probar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cualquier duda acá andamos

Comment: Ok, nuevamente gracias. Saludos

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aeptada.. Saludos